# Page break not working rotated html page?

Tags: html, css

I want to print A4 size paper **TWO column**. So i split the page. here i used

```
display: block; page-break-before: always;
```

Its worked fine. But after page break content not showing.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/VamrMY?editors=1100)**

I need after page break content continue on next div. **It is possible?**

### ***Expected Results Like [this](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/pyNdxZ)***

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the last paragraph from the first div, into the second div, and run.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font: 14px "Tahoma";
 line-height:28px
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-center{
 text-align:center;
}
.regno li,   .answer_block div,.answer_block div p{
 display:inline-block;
 
}
.page {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.subpage {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
      margin-left: 160px;
    margin-top: -165px;
    
 width: 180mm;
     height: 267mm;
}

.subpage.second{
   margin-left: 160px;
    margin-top: -280px;
   
}
  
      

 
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
 html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
 
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
p {
   display: block; page-break-before: always;        
}
    
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
   <div class="subpage" >
          <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="subpage second" > 
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```